# How to use multiple style in PHPWord?

Tags: php, phpword

Actually I am using following code In PhpWord

```
$table->addCell(10500, $styleCell)->addText('<span style="background-color:#003300;">Test</span><span style="background-color:#00000;">Dinesh</span>');
$table->addRow();
```

Please Help to solve my problem...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the altering cell content coloring by creating a textrun and adding the different colored parts separately:

```
$textrun = $table->addCell(10500, $styleCell)->addTextRun()
$textrun->addText(htmlspecialchars("Test", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), array('color' => '003300'));
$textrun->addText(htmlspecialchars("Dinesh", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), array('color' => '000000'));
$table->addRow();
```